# Codeigniter active record COUNT return null

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, count

I need to select some data from a table and count related images from another table.
The code I'm using is the following ( from model file)

```
$this->rci_db->select (" 
        $this->tbl_register.id,
        $this->tbl_register.cor,
        DATE_FORMAT($this->tbl_register.registerdate, '%d/%m/%Y') AS registerdate,
        $this->tbl_registrations.registration,
        $this->tbl_aircrafts.cn,
        $this->tbl_aircrafts.built,
        $this->tbl_manufacturers.manufacturer, 
        $this->tbl_models.type AS model,
        COUNT($this->tbl_images.imgid) AS count
        ");
    $this->rci_db->from("$this->tbl_register");
    $this->rci_db->join("$this->tbl_registrations", "$this->tbl_registrations.rid = $this->tbl_register.rid", 'left');
    $this->rci_db->join("$this->tbl_aircrafts", "$this->tbl_register.aid = $this->tbl_aircrafts.aid", 'left');
    $this->rci_db->join("$this->tbl_manufacturers", "$this->tbl_manufacturers.mid = $this->tbl_aircrafts.mid", 'left');
    $this->rci_db->join("$this->tbl_models", "$this->tbl_models.tid = $this->tbl_aircrafts.tid", 'left');
    $this->rci_db->join("$this->tbl_images", "$this->tbl_register.id = $this->tbl_images.id", 'left');

    $this->rci_db->where("$this->tbl_register.rid", $rid);

    $query = $this->rci_db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query->result();
    }
    return false;
```

The query return null for the COUNT statement and I'm not able to figure out what's wrong.
Other data are returned correctly
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That count is in another table, so you must relate those somehow in your query. Instead of joining in this case it might be easy to just use a sub select.

Something like this in your select:

```
$this->rci_db->select (" 
        $this->tbl_register.id,
        $this->tbl_register.cor,
        DATE_FORMAT($this->tbl_register.registerdate, '%d/%m/%Y') AS registerdate,
        $this->tbl_registrations.registration,
        $this->tbl_aircrafts.cn,
        $this->tbl_aircrafts.built,
        $this->tbl_manufacturers.manufacturer, 
        $this->tbl_models.type AS model,
        (SELECT COUNT($this->tbl_images.imgid) FROM $this->tbl_images WHERE $this->tbl_register.id = $this->tbl_images.id) AS count
        ");
```